# I am trying to use static files like css and images in my django project but statics files are not displayed in my template page

Tags: django

I want a image to be displayed in my navbar at the top left corner but its not visible and my css styling is also not styling my pages....in short my static files are not displayed in my project.
i think i have mentioned all the neccesary things if anything is missing please mention.

my settings.py----

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')


STATIC_FILES = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_files')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static','static_root')
```

urls.py---

```
from Devishi import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('product/',views.products,name ='product'),
    path('customer/',views.customer,name ='customer'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

main.html---

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title>{% block title %}DASHBORD||{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/my.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include 'app/navbar.html' %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    <hr/>
      <p>Our Footer</p>

  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

navbar.html---

```
{% load static %}

<style media="screen">
.hello-msg{
  font-size:18px;
  color:#fff;
  margin-right:20px;
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <img src="{% static "img/logo.png" %}" alt="image">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'product' %}">Products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: There's no `STATIC_FILES` setting in Django. I think you meant [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs).

Comment: yes i meant the same